# Part of datagridview text to be a link

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a datagridview which is populated by a SqlDataSource.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlEnvComments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Kunskapshjulet %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [EnvComment] FROM [MealItems], [Products] 
                       WHERE ([MealID] = @MealID)
                       AND [MealItems].[ProductID] = [Products].[ProductID]
                       AND [EnvComment] is not null">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="MealID" SessionField="MealID" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlEnvComments" ShowHeader="False" BackColor ="White"
        EmptyDataText="There are no envComments">
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="Alt"/>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I would like to achieve the possibility that part of the text displayed in the datagridview could be a link to another website.

e.g. if EnvComment is

```
"Read more about Boxing Day at <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_Day">Wikipedia</a>"
```

there would be a link which would redirect to wikipedia.

Is is possible to achieve this?

Comment: the code shows that the bound columns of the grid are not exposes to HTML source, once you do that you can use link type column or try with anchor tag as you are trying with that wikipedia link. To get columns check AutoGenerateColumns property of grid view

Comment: How do I expose the column to HTML source?